# Can't add files for staging

Tags: git, github

I've got some files i'd like to commit to my github repo, and I created the branch I'd like to used to track my changes.  I create it from the terminal using

```
git checkout -b my_branch
```

I've created the branch in the directory where the files are located.  When I run `ls` to view the files in the directory, I have the following:

```
folder_where_files_are
other_random_file
```

But when I run `git status` the directory where the files I'd like to track are located do not show as untracked, *but* the `other_random_file` does show as untracked.  Further, when I do `git add`, it doesn't throw an error, but when I go to commit it says.

```
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to 
track)
```

1. Why isn't it showing the files in the directory i'm in?
2. Why can't I add files for staging?

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: `I've created the branch in the directory` you do not create branches in directories. you create directories in repositories and the repository can have git. I assume, you are in the wrong directory using git

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @caramba I figured out the issue.  I need to move the directory I wanted to track *into* the local version of the repo that I set up.  I was able to solve my problem by with the following:

```
mv folder_where_files_are/ local_git_repo
```

This moved my files to the proper place.  Now when I `git status` the directory shows as untracked.  I was able to add, commit and push from there.